# Javascript Speech Recognition Can't Get Voice Input within Class

Tags: javascript, html, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, speech-to-text

I am having issues with receiving and storing voice input using the JavaScript Speech Recognition API. I followed some tutorials and set up everything correctly and got the code to work just fine. Then I decided to create a class called AI that could store the most recent input, and eventually add some sort of speech parsing methods. But when I put the recognition.onresult function within the class, the voice commands were not stored into the ai.recentCommand variable. Instead it would just print "none". Here is what I have so far.

```
class AI {
  constructor() {
    this.recentCommand = "none";
    this.recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
    this.recognition.lang = 'en-US';
    this.recognition.interimResults = false;
    this.recognition.maxAlternatives = 5;
  }
  getInput() {
    this.recognition.onresult = function(event) {
        this.recentCommand = event.results[0][0].transcript;}
    this.recognition.start();
  }
}

var button = document.getElementById("button");
var output = document.getElementById("output");

var ai = new AI();

// Gets input fine, but I want to use the getInput() method instead
ai.recognition.onresult = function(event) {
  ai.recentCommand = event.results[0][0].transcript;
}
ai.recognition.start();

// I want to get the input through the ai.getInput() method, but isn't working
ai.getInput();

button.addEventListener("click", function() {output.innerHTML =
    ai.recentCommand});
```

Does it have something to do with a function being within a function? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please give your question a proper title that reflects the problem. Also explain what do you mean by "refused to work".

Comment: Sorry, first post to this website. I'll go ahead and change the title.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback/20279485#20279485

Comment: Javascript insanity, basically you are accessing the wrong 'this'.

Comment: Thanks for the comment